# julia writedlm adding extra quotes when there are quotes within a string

Tags: julia

I'm reading a file into a list of strings using new-lines as separators. I'm changing a few of the lines, then writing that list back to the file. This adds in extra quotation marks only on certain lines.

This might be a bug in `writedlm`. Most of the file is written with the expected behavior. It appears to mess up when there are quotes within the string. Any idea why this is happening, how to fix it, or where to report this if it's a bug?

Code:

```
file = "og_file.F"
new_file = "new_file.F"
f = read(file, String)
meta = split(f, "\n")
writedlm(new_file, meta)
```

Original file:

```
#include "DARWIN_OPTIONS.h"

CBOP
C !ROUTINE: DARWIN_PLANKTON
C !INTERFACE: ==========================================================
      SUBROUTINE DARWIN_PLANKTON(
     I     Ptr,
     U     gTr,
     O     chlout, diags,
     I     PAR, photoTempFunc, hetTempFunc, grazTempFunc, reminTempFunc,
     I     mortTempFunc, mort2TempFunc, uptakeTempFunc,
#ifdef DARWIN_DEBUG
     I     iG, jG, k, dT,
#endif
     I     myTime,myIter,myThid)

C !DESCRIPTION:

C !USES: ===============================================================
      IMPLICIT NONE
#ifdef ALLOW_RADTRANS
#include "RADTRANS_SIZE.h"
#endif
#include "DARWIN_SIZE.h"
#include "DARWIN_INDICES.h"
#include "DARWIN_DIAGS.h"
#include "DARWIN_RADTRANS.h"
#include "DARWIN_PARAMS.h"
#include "DARWIN_TRAITS.h"
```

output file:

```
"#include ""DARWIN_OPTIONS.h"""

CBOP
C !ROUTINE: DARWIN_PLANKTON
C !INTERFACE: ==========================================================
      SUBROUTINE DARWIN_PLANKTON(
     I     Ptr,
     U     gTr,
     O     chlout, diags,
     I     PAR, photoTempFunc, hetTempFunc, grazTempFunc, reminTempFunc,
     I     mortTempFunc, mort2TempFunc, uptakeTempFunc,
#ifdef DARWIN_DEBUG
     I     iG, jG, k, dT,
#endif
     I     myTime,myIter,myThid)

C !DESCRIPTION:

C !USES: ===============================================================
      IMPLICIT NONE
#ifdef ALLOW_RADTRANS
"#include ""RADTRANS_SIZE.h"""
#endif
"#include ""DARWIN_SIZE.h"""
"#include ""DARWIN_INDICES.h"""
"#include ""DARWIN_DIAGS.h"""
"#include ""DARWIN_RADTRANS.h"""
"#include ""DARWIN_PARAMS.h"""
"#include ""DARWIN_TRAITS.h"""
```

Answer (score 1):

This is intended. The reason is that `writedlm` is intended to write tabular data (having multiple fields per one line). In this case a standard behavior is to use double quotes `"` to wrap fields that contain them, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values:

> More sophisticated CSV implementations permit them, often by requiring " (double quote) characters around values that contain reserved characters (such as commas, double quotes, or less commonly, newlines). Embedded double quote characters may then be represented by a pair of consecutive double quotes

For your use case instead it is better to use e.g.:

```
file = "og_file.F"
new_file = "new_file.F"
meta = readlines(file)
open(new_file, "w") do io
    foreach(line -> println(io, line), meta)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for explaining why this is the expected behavior!

I solved it by adding in the keyword arg for quotes (based off of [this answer](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-specify-no-quotes-around-strings-in-writedlm/1380) from julia hub). There is no easily accessible documentation about it, had to look at the [source code](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/cfac61d88625e3d58b9f0dbd4d9959e640b2a9f0/base/datafmt.jl#L364) for `writedlm`.

```
writedlm(new_file, meta, quotes=false)
```